# remember wireless password in kde

Tags: wireless, password, kde

I've got kubuntu 12.04.3 LTS installed. Don't know why - whether it's a default option or I've made this - but KDE always keeps asking me for the wireless connection password and it's annoying a little bit. Each time I reboot I have to enter kde wallet password.

What can I do to grant access to the kde wallet for the wireless network manager?

Comment: I found this: [https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kde-asks-for-wifi-password-at-every-login/5224](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kde-asks-for-wifi-password-at-every-login/5224) I hope it helps

Answer (score 14):

If that version of KDE has Network manager try opening network connections, go to the wireless tab and edit (or add) your wireless network info, making sure to check the box "available to all users." It won't ask for the wireless password again.

Comment: How do you make this behaviour happen by default???

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is a wee-bit old, but if someone else has the same issue these days, here is how it worked for me under KDE Neon 5.10 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS):

Setting up the system I must have disabled a feature called KWallet (probably thinking it had something to do with online payment). Thereafter, it would always ask me for the password again, and I didn t pay it any mind as I rebooted only a few times since then.

Enabling the Kwallet again under "Settings->User Accounts->Kwallet"
resolved this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's a small spanner icon in the top right hand cornor of the popup window when you click on the wifi connection icon in the task bar.

This opens the Connection Editor, where you can edit the wifi connection and allow all users to use the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Following @elder-geek's suggestion, I noticed that my connection didn't have the password saved. (Connection editor -> Edit Connection 'X' -> Wireless Security). If you put the password in this tab and hit OK, it should save it.

Answer (score 0):

From system setting go to connections. Under Known Wi-Fi's find your  connection. In the Wi-Fi security tab type Wi-Fi password in field. Also check connect automatically with priority and set priority (probably you want to be 0) in general tab.

Answer (score 0):

Even after disabling  Kwallet it prompting for password then go to Setting->connections->Your_wifi_name Then go to WiFi tab and check whether there is password stored or not.If not then Enter your password there and click on OK.