# Remove kdewallet password without being prompted for wifi password

Tags: wireless, kubuntu, password, kde

I would like to boot my computer and it automatically connect to the wifi without typing in any passwords. I've found online how to disable the kdewallet using kwalletmanager and that works - but if I do that I'm prompted to enter the wifi password every time instead of the kdewallet password.

Is there a way to not have to type neither the kdewallet password nor the wifi password every time I turn on the computer?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Elder Geek](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek) in answer to [a similar question from last year](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433912/remember-wireless-password-in-kde), "If that version of KDE has Network manager try opening network connections, go to the wireless tab and edit (or add) your wireless network info, making sure to check the box "available to all users." It won't ask for the wireless password again."